# How can I re-use a form controller within different JSF managed beans?

Tags: jsf, ejb

I currently have a ViewScoped bean that manages the editing of an Entity.  Some of the Entity's fields are bound to pull-downs that are backed by lists that change depending upon other pulldown selections.  I decided to use an inner class to handle these pulldowns and it works great!

I'd like to re-use this inner class in other beans, though, because there are other Entity's that also could use this pulldown logic.  I don't know the best way to architect this though.  Here are some ideas:

- If I make this pulldown class its own ViewScoped bean, then I need a way to instantiate it with the Entity that is using it.  The original ViewScoped Bean that is using this takes in a ID URL param and queries the database for the entity in the post contstruct.  If I'm using multiple ViewScoped beans, then I'd have to query the DB multiple times and I don't want to do that.
- I could try making it a regular Java class, but then I lose access to the EJB it uses to populate the pulldowns.
- I could make it an abstract class and then make every managed bean that uses it implement the pulldown population method itself, but this seems kind of icky.

Here's a mockup of what I'm currently using:

```
@ViewScoped
public class EntityController {

    @EJB
    private EntityFacade entityFacade;
    @EJB
    private PulldownFacade pulldownFacade;

    private Entity entity;
    private PulldownController pulldownController;

    @PostContruct
    public void init() {
        entity = entityFacade.getEntity(param);
        pulldownController = new PulldownController();
    }

    public class PulldownController {


        public PulldownController() {               
        }

        public List<String> getPulldown() {
            List<String> list = facade.getPulldown();
            modifyThePulldownList(entity, list);
            return list;
        }
    }
}

<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value=#{entityController.pulldownController.pulldown}/>
</h:form>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you should do is to encapsulate getPulldown() logic in a method implemented within an abstract class. Therefore, each subsequent implementation will use this implementation. This approach would support both DRY and KISS principles.

There is also no problem with accessing EJB via @EJB within an abstract class and getPulldown() can use this field directly as it uses it in your example.